# Arcade Dashboard List Formatting - Rename Fields and Sum Stats

Tags: arcade, dashboard

I have a dataset from a Survey123 and my goal is to add a list element in the dashboard that shows the top 3 students based on the number of birds they identified by sight. I imagine I will use an IF/THEN statement to filter out the number or birds by sight (since that is a survey field they selected). I am running into issues on the student names. Some of them inputted their names in various ways for each survey such as "John Smith", "John", "John S". My current thoughts are to replace or group those options so any variation of John will be grouped together.

Has anyone done this? Is this something I can use the GroupBy function in Arcade for?